# Can't get the serial number with Exif

Tags: python, exif

I'm trying to get the serial number from the camera with python following this code:

```
data = image_exif.has_exif

logger.debug('Has EXIF: {}'.format(data))
report_tmp = image + ', {}'.format(data)
report_data.append(report_tmp + '\n')
...            
exif_value = image_exif.get("SerialNumber")
report_tmp = '{}: {}'.format("SerialNumber", exif_value)

logger.debug('{}'.format(report_tmp))
report_data.append(report_tmp + '\n')
```

But it says 'None', and I don't understand why, because I'm checking exif data in Photoshop/Lightroom and both are showing the serial number.

```
[DEBUG] :: File to process: C:\...\image.jpg
[DEBUG] :: Has EXIF: True
**[DEBUG] :: CameraSerialNumber: None**
[DEBUG] :: datetime_original: 2019:10:25 16:12:36
[DEBUG] :: software: Adobe Photoshop CC 2018 (Windows)
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried different values such as CameraSerialNumber, LensSerialNumber, SerialNumber, InternalSerialNumber, BodySerialNumber and it's all the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that image has this value? Did you check it using programs which can display exif ? Maybe this value doesn't exist in file.

Comment: I'm checking it with Photoshop and Lightroom and both shows it. Should I try with another program? I know that Adobe is using format XMP, but don't know if there's any problem with it. I'll investigate how to extract metadata via XMP.

Comment: I used Google to find information about `exif SerialNumber` and I found only that `SerialNumber` is not standard element and different cameras may put it in different way.

Comment: Yes, I checked Nikon tags ( https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Nikon.html ) and it's SerialNumber. I've also tried with Canon tags and different cameras but still didn't work.

Comment: Problem solved. Got it with body_serial_number instead of BodySerialNumber.